# Where are input events from non-mouse/keyboard USB peripherals (e.g. the buttons on a scanner) sent in Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, scanner, input, peripherals

When I plug in a device like a mouse or a keyboard it shows up as an entry in `/dev/input/by-id` and I can read bytes from that entry to see what input events have occurred, such as keystrokes and button clicks.

I have an ES-50 USB scanner and it has a big button on it. This normally is pressed to begin scanning a page, but on Linux it doesn't do anything. I assume that input event goes *somewhere* in the operating system. How would I watch for that event and handle it like with `/dev/input`?

If this has any relevance, I do have the driver for this scanner installed and functional. However I have to initiate a scan from the command line, which is less than ideal.

Thanks!

Comment: The button you mentioned is probably a *soft* button, i.e., driver/software dependent. As it happens with other products and many other Epson scanners the Windows drivers are full-featured but the Linux ones are just generic.

Answer (score 0):

Quite possibly nowhere. You'll only have kernel "input" events if the kernel actually knows how to demultiplex that from the 'scanner' bits – and that won't happen if the entire scanner driver is in the userspace programs that directly talk to the device via raw USB, which I believe most do.

(There's no "scanner" device subsystem in the kernel as far as I know...)

In that case the kernel doesn't know what's happening and scanner software (SANE) will be the one that needs to originate these events. It *could* emit virtual input events via uinput but as far as I know SANE doesn't do that.

(Note: I've never used SANE as it doesn't support my scanner yet.)